# React-Leaflet is not working on react native mobile application

Tags: android, react-native, gis, mobile-application, react-leaflet

React-Leaflet is not working on react native mobile application. I'm using expo CLI.

I made a project using **expo init projectname** command. I have made the basic UI but when I import the react leaflet into the code. it gives an error.

Comment: What error? Post the whole error message as well as the code that throws it.

Comment: there is no error in the code. i think it's logical error. perhaps react leaflet doesnt work on expo go. I'm making it in a java file, with the blank template . 



the error was 500 something. maybe the html and css code weren't being connected to the react leaflet map code in the App.js file. Any tutorial or any help that you could suggest to make a map in a android application using react leaflet and expo.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`react-leaflet` is a React UI library built with html tags (div, span, etc). Those tags don't work in React Native, so you can't use the library as written in React Native.